# Asp.net 5 beta8/rc1, 502 the specified CGI application, Azure [SOLUTION]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core

During recent events (RC1 release, Azure updates...), my asp.net 5, beta8 web app hosted on Azure, started giving me a

> 502 the specified cgi application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process

during ajax/angularjs http calls. This happens in every browser, but only in certain requests. It does not happen in local debugging, but only when published to Azure.

See my comment for a solution that worked for me :)

Comment: This question is simply put to help people with the new release of asp.net 5 and Azure. If they get this error, google will guide them here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trouble and many many hours, I found a solution for my problem: In `Startup.cs` I added `app.UseIISPlatformHandler();`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    { 
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler(); //this line
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();            
        //app.UseMvc();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action?}/{id?}");

        });
    }
```

And in project.json I added

> "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8"

```
 "dependencies": {
...
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
...
}
```

Maybe this can help you out.

Comment: [I have the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416996/asp-net-5-rc1-bad-gateway-the-specified-cgi-application-encountered-an-error), but I already have IISPlatformHandler set up. Using RC1.

Comment: Hosted on Azure? Delete the web app and create it again. Make sure RC1 package is downloaded and installed. If needed, create a new project. That might also work :)