# ASP.NET 5 (RC1) Bad Gateway: The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I am running an ASP.NET 5 project in an Azure Web App.

When calling on an API endpoint with a file (form-data) of about 1.5mb or larger, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` with the follow message in the reponse body:

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process.

The strange thing is that when uploading a smaller file, the call works fine. It seems to produce the `502` at around the 1.5mb mark, but it's not entirely consistent.

I am using ASP.NET 5 RC1.

In Startup.cs, I have `app.UseIISPlatformHandler();` as the first middleware addition in the `Configure()` method.

**`project.config:`**

```
{
  ...
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.6",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "5.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    ...
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
}
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Jessevl, the following exception is being thrown:

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unexpected end of request content at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.d__39.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.d__36.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.Internal.FormFeature.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.FormValueProviderFactory.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__49.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__44.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.InnerAttributeRoute.d__10.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet.RequestTrackingMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Http.Frame.d__79.MoveNext()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be some sort of issue with the current release of Asp.Net 5 where the error returned when running in an Azure Web App will always be

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

regardless of what the actual error is. I, for example, got this error when I had an incorrect connection string to Azure Event Hub somewhere in my code.

You could try remote debugging (see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug)) or simply scan your logs using Kudu, which you can find on [websitename].scm.azurewebsites.net (replace [websitename] with what would normally be in [websitename].azurewebsites.net), or Visual Studio server explorer.

Jesse

Comment: Absolutely correct! I have edited my post with the exception details but will mark this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: New question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418128/asp-net-5-rc1-system-io-invaliddataexception-unexpected-end-of-request-content)