# ASP.NET 5 RC1: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unexpected end of request content

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I am running an ASP.NET 5 project in an Azure Web App.

When calling on an API endpoint with a file (form-data) of about 1.5mb or larger, the following exception is thrown.

[Here is where the exception is thrown from](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/Http/MessageBody.cs#L174).

Does anyone know how this can be fixed? Is there a possible workaround?

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unexpected end of request content at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.d__39.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
--- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.Internal.FormFeature.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.FormValueProviderFactory.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.InnerAttributeRoute.d__10.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
--- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
--- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
--- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet.RequestTrackingMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Http.Frame.d__79.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Hi, @davenewza, did you solved it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I filed this on [aspnet/KestrelHttpServer](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer). It has been accepted as a bug and  has recently been included into the 1.0.0-rc2 milestone.  [See issue here](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/520).

Answer (score 1):

Well, remember ASP.NEt 5 still being in RC, so maybe in your VS the current version is even more inmature, this error looks a little bit weird but looks like a web server error. The web server part of asp.net 5 is kestrell and that match with your stack trace `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel`

I'm going to recommend you

1. Update your Kestrell server assemblies to [last RC Nov 18](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/releases) your VS could be waiting for that update.
2. If the error persist post an issue in [Kestrell ASP.Net 5 GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues) this could be a bug related to others already opened talking about content lenght https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/labels/bug

Comment: I am using the RC1 packages (not the RC2 nightlies). I have made an issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/520).